# Mathematical representation of a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, math, modeling

This might me a ridiculous question.
I created mathematical model using Python and I know that I started this from the end, but I need write mathematical equations for the documentation.
The equation has multidimensional array in it.
So my question is how to present multidimensional array in mathematical way?

Comment: This is quite vague. Since we don't know what you are talking about it is hard to give any concrete advice. In many contexts a 3-dimensional array might be thought of as a 1-parameter family of 2-dimensional matrices. Why not provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of dimensions in your array is one, you can represent it as a vector, or perhaps a tuple. But this almost certainly is not what you mean by "multidimensional."

If the number of dimensions is two, you can use a matrix.

If the number of dimensions is greater than two, you can use a tensor. [Here is a Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#As_multidimensional_arrays) explaining a little how tensors and multidimensional arrays are related. A search will give you many more such pages. Tensors include vectors and matrices, so this is the most general solution, though vectors and matrices are much more well known.